# How to get all ID's from joined collection with having condition on joined tables in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I want to get all IDs from collection using `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract::getAllIds()` method.

My collection is joined with orders table:

```
$collection
     ->getSelect()
     ->joinLeft(
         ['o' => $this->getTable('sales/order')], // Table and alias
         'main_table.order_id = o.increment_id', // Join condition
         [ // Select fields
             'store_id' => 'store_id',
             'order_created_at' => 'created_at'
         ]);
```

But when I want to get all ID's from that collection with a having condition:

```
$collection->getSelect()->having('order_created_at >= ?', '20-02-2016 0:00:00')
$ids = $collection->getAllIds();
```

It gives me an error: `Unknown column 'order_created_at' in 'having clause'`, because `getAllIds()` method resets collections' select columns and there is no way to filter by joined columns:

```
public function getAllIds()
{
    $idsSelect = clone $this->getSelect();
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::ORDER);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_COUNT);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::LIMIT_OFFSET);
    $idsSelect->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS); // Reset columns here

    $idsSelect->columns($this->getResource()->getIdFieldName(), 'main_table');
    return $this->getConnection()->fetchCol($idsSelect);
}
```

So how to retreive joined collection ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `where` instead of `having`.

```
$collection->getSelect()->where('order_created_at >= ?', '20-02-2016 0:00:00')
```

Or add `order_created_at` field to your `select`:

```
$collection
  ->getSelect()
  ->from($this->getTable('sales/order'), '*')
  ...
```

`having` requires fields to be in your results. It filters **after** your select instead of filtering the select itself as `where` does.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to use `where` on a column alias before, but it didn't work and I don't know why. After your advice I decided to get rid of alias and now all works fine.

Comment: Figured out, why isn't worked before with column alias: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html